# Extract ID and value from set of strings in an array

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having difficulty solving the following problem.

I have a pandas `df['subjects']` which has a list of strings.

```
df['subjects'].head(3) = 

0['B:1187', 'B:1188', 'P:123456', 'B:62']
1['G:1', 'G:1C', 'G:21', 'G:3', 'G:30']
2['B:71', 'E:D', 'G:6J', 'P:125467', 'B:1296', 'P:789456']
```

Essentially what I need is the following..

```
df['subjects'] = 
123456
None
125467,789456
```

I just need to return the values that have `P:XXXXX`

I've tried using a for loop but I keep getting the wrong values.

Comment: _I've tried using a for loop but I keep getting the wrong values._ Can you share that code? Why do you have lists stored like this in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

We can do `explode` then using `startswith` + `split` before `groupby`

```
s=df['subjects'].explode()
s=s[s.str.startswith('P:')].str.split(':').str[-1].groupby(level=0).agg(list).reindex(df.index)
0            [123456]
1                 NaN
2    [125467, 789456]
Name: subjects, dtype: object
df['new']=s
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Using `explode`, `Series.where` and `GroupBy`:

```
dfn = df['subjects'].explode()
dfn = dfn.where(dfn.str[0].eq('P')).dropna().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
dfn = dfn.str.replace('P:', '').to_frame().reindex(df.index)

        subjects
0         123456
1            NaN
2  125467,789456
```

---

#### One-liner with `DataFrame.apply`

Note: this solution is not preferred because of efficiency

```
dfn = (
    df['subjects'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([val.split(':')[1] for val in x if 'P:' in val]))
    .to_frame()
)


         subjects
0          123456
1                
2  125467, 789456
```

Comment: Hi - when I try to do the first method I get the following error. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: I think I know why. Its because I have an old version of pandas. '0.20.1'

Comment: Yes that is correct, `explode` is available from `pandas >= 0.25.0` and onwards.

Comment: @Cesar can you please address my comments regarding your question, it is still lacking.

Comment: @Erfan I have the correct libraries now. However I still get the following error. AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using explode:

```
(
    df.subjects
    .apply(lambda x: ','.join([v[2:] for v in x if v.startswith('P:')]))
    .replace('', np.nan)
)

6           123456
7              NaN
8    125467,789456
Name: subjects, dtype: object
```